# WrapperManager cannot be resolved error: Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, service, java-service-wrapper, tanuki

I am trying to implement the example given here: http://benjsicam.me/blog/running-a-java-application-as-a-windows-service-part-1-tutorial/ 
The code basically turns a Java application into a service. The application outputs Date and Time to the console at specific intervals. The whole project gets exported to a **runnable** JAR file, with required libraries in a separate folder. All I have to do is modify the **wrapper.conf** file to run Main.jar (which is the exported JAR) and put the exported libraries in the lib folder. 
I have followed everything exactly, but I am getting the following problem: **WrapperManager cannot be resolved**. I am including the links for snapshots which show the Maven project structure, the contents of POM.xml, and code contents of four Java files. Also included are the required source files in Google Drive.

Java version jdk1.8.0_11

[Main.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnaWIgBd3AjZHVsVGZVSVJlbkk/edit?usp=sharing)

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxnaWIgBd3AjZlZJOUhkblRWdFU&usp=sharing)

Error Shown:
[image: WrapperManager cannot be resolved]

Wrapper.conf file (removed most of the comments+top part)

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=batch_Proc.main_prog.Main

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../lib/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=../lib/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.6=../lib/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.7=../lib/spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.8=../lib/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.9=../lib/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.10=../lib/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.11=../lib/wrappertest.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.12=Main.jar


# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=FALSE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1=

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
wrapper.debug=FALSE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Test Wrapper Sample Application

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Ignore output from dumping the configuration to the console.  This is only needed by the TestWrapper sample application.)
wrapper.filter.trigger.999=wrapper.filter.trigger.*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.999=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.999=NONE
#  Ignore -verbose:class output to avoid false positives.
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=[Loaded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1000=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1001=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1001=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1001=The JVM has run out of memory.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Email Notifications. (Requires Professional Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Common Event Email settings.
#wrapper.event.default.email.debug=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.host=<SMTP_Host>
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.port=25
#wrapper.event.default.email.subject=[%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%:%WRAPPER_NAME%:%WRAPPER_EVENT_NAME%] Event Notification
#wrapper.event.default.email.sender=<Sender email>
#wrapper.event.default.email.recipient=<Recipient email>

# Configure the log attached to event emails.
#wrapper.event.default.email.attach_log=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.lines=50
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.format=LPTM
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.loglevel=INFO

# Enable specific event emails.
#wrapper.event.wrapper_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_prelaunch.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_started.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_deadlock.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stop.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stopped.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_failed_invocation.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_max_failed_invocations.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_kill.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_killed.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_unexpected_exit.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.wrapper_stop.email=TRUE

# Specify custom mail content
wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email.body=The JVM was restarted.\n\nPlease check on its status.\n

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=JavaWindowsServiceSample

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=Java Windows Service Sample

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=A sample java windows service application

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START, DELAY_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem! I had made a simple mistake of not making sure the correct dependencies were downloaded in Maven.
The required jars for WrapperManager and WrapperListener were not available which were causing the errors.